# PDF Compression using iText (resizing images)

Tags: java, pdf, compression, itext, transparency

I am trying to reduce a size of PDF using iText. In my code I resize the existing images. I found an example of the code at http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=286 and modified it. It's reducing the size but the images are returned as jpg, so they have a white background. Obviously JPG does not support transparency. I've changed the code to write back as png image and some other things (like DCTDECODE filter to FLATEDECODE and BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB to ARGB). But it's not working. Pdf can't be open (Insufficient data for an image). Any ideas what am I missing? Here is my code:

```
    float FACTOR = 0.5f;
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);  
    int n = reader.getXrefSize();
    PdfObject object;
    PRStream stream;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        object = reader.getPdfObject(i);
        if (object == null || !object.isStream())
            continue;
        stream = (PRStream)object;

        PdfObject pdfsubtype = stream.get(PdfName.SUBTYPE);
        if (pdfsubtype != null &&    pdfsubtype.toString().equals(PdfName.IMAGE.toString())) {

            PdfImageObject image = new PdfImageObject(stream);                 
            BufferedImage bi = image.getBufferedImage();
            if (bi == null) continue;
            int width = (int)(bi.getWidth() * FACTOR);
            int height = (int)(bi.getHeight() * FACTOR);
            BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
            AffineTransform at = AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(FACTOR, FACTOR);
            Graphics2D g = img.createGraphics();
            g.drawRenderedImage(bi, at);
            ByteArrayOutputStream imgBytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ImageIO.write(img, "png", imgBytes);
            g.dispose();

            stream.clear();
            stream.setData(imgBytes.toByteArray(), false, PRStream.BEST_COMPRESSION);
            stream.put(PdfName.TYPE, PdfName.XOBJECT);
            stream.put(PdfName.SUBTYPE, PdfName.IMAGE);
            stream.put(PdfName.FILTER, PdfName.FLATEDECODE);
            stream.put(PdfName.WIDTH, new PdfNumber(width));
            stream.put(PdfName.HEIGHT, new PdfNumber(height));
            stream.put(PdfName.BITSPERCOMPONENT, new PdfNumber(8));
            stream.put(PdfName.COLORSPACE, PdfName.DEVICERGB);
            imgBytes.flush();
            imgBytes.close();
        }
    }
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    stamper.close();
    reader.close();
```

Comment: try setting this enum to png http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/parser/PdfImageObject.ImageBytesType.html

Comment: You might want to read this answer, too: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20814205/231316

Comment: Chris, thanks for the link. Indeed, images come as two opaque.